# MYSQL ERROR 1054 (42S22) complaint about Unknown column in 'field list' that does not exist

Tags: mysql

```
$ mysql -u admin -pABC123 db < backup.sql
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 365438: Unknown column 'NTLL' in 'field list'
$ grep -E -i -e 'NTLL' backup.sql || echo "NTLL IS NEVER USED"
NTLL IS NEVER USED
```

line 365438 (which is essentially the same as the three hundred thousand lines before it...) looks like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tableName` (`a`, `b_u`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g_h`, `i_j`, `k_l`, `m_n`, `o_p`, `q`, `r`)
VALUES ('s_t',1.55923,1.55434,1.55932,1.55443,1.55919,1.55429,1.55932,1.55443,1.55919,1.55429,NULL,'2015-11-15 07:12:10');
```

obviously `NTLL` is not used...

lets check the table it self:

```
$ mysql> show create table tableName;
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `a` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `b_u` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `g_h` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_j` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `k_l` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_n` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_p` decimal(16,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  UNIQUE KEY `a_r_index` (`a`,`r`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `r_index` (`r`,`a`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

what on earth is *`NTLL`*????

## UPDATE

also noticed the same issue but this time with column `b^u` which is very similar to the real column `b_u` but, it's still not the same...

```
$ grep -E -i -e 'b\^u' backup-2.sql || echo "b^u IS NEVER USED"
b^u IS NEVER USED
```

also of note is that there are no known triggers in use in the database:

```
mysql>show triggers;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

since `b^u` looks like `b_u`, it may be worth mentioning that `NTLL` is *almost* like `NULL`...

Comment: Post output of grep from above to see what line(s) contain NTLL

Comment: The first thing I look for when I can't find the column it's complaining about is triggers..

Comment: @dbug that was the output `false` (aka exit status 1)

Comment: @sebastian-hallin `mysql> show triggers;` `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I'd bet money that NTLL is a corruption of NULL. Note that `^` is ASCII 94, `_` is ASCII 95. Same relationship between `T` and `U`. How are you receiving this file? Is it stored remotely?

Comment: @miken32 that sounds like the cause, it's stored locally on a two usb  external drives used as a single raid1 array.  I'm splitting the files into parts to see if I can at least narrow down the issue.

Comment: That has frightening implications for the rest of your data!

Comment: @miken32 I think I should of pushed a little harder for raid-6 storage...

Comment: what's worse is that there are no error notices from mdadm or linux

Comment: more or less confirmed that it was a drive issue as I split the backup into several parts and ran them individually without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID is not enough, if you are using ext4 be certain that your os doesn't default to the ext4 option `data=ordered` it results in ZERO safety checks on how your data is read or written, for safety use `mount -o rw,relatime,nodelalloc,journal_checksum,data=journal ...`

## UPDATE

in fact it turns out that ext4 doesn't do any data integrity on the data (only the meta-data), the best solution is to NOT use raid or ext4 and switch to ZFS as this can mirror your data and correct any bit rot that happens.

## UPDATE

Even with ZFS bit rot can still happen if you don't have ecc memory installed, since the bit rot can happen in memory before ZFS has a chance to safely write it to disk.

Comment: This is quite old, but for now *btrfs* provides data checksumming so it can protect data on its builtin raid1 in case of rare hw errors.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL errors are most of the time self-explanatory.  In this specific case, the error message states clearly that the problem exists somewhere in the 365438th line of the "backup.sql"

To solve the problem, you should:

Eliminate the 365438th line of the "backup.sql" file and then `mysql -u admin -pABC123 db < backup.sql` again, knowing that the problem may happen again as there is no certainty what the exact issue is at the given line, or, extract the 365438th line of the "backup.sql" file, analyze it, and correct all errors of the sort (personally I would go awk/sed).

Most likely the problem is an unmatched quote and/or a special character that is breaking execution of the insert statement.